# java execution from shared folder

Tags: java

I've a java file in a shared folder which has to be executed. I tried using the following for execution

```
set JAVA_HOME=\\[servername]\[sharedfolder]\j2sdk\jdk1.5.0_04
set CLASSPATH= "the directory with the classes"
%JAVA_HOME%/bin/javaw -cp "%CLASSPATH%" [name of the class with the main method]
```

but when i gave javac  , it says that javac is not a recognizable command or argument. Is there any other way of executing java files in shared folder?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: can you specify the OS you are trying on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that Tom gave a UNC style path, and used a Microsoft Windows environment variable expansion, here is an example that works for Windows.

You could map the share to a drive letter and then set your `JAVA_HOME` variable to that.

For example:

```
net use j: \\[servername]\[sharedfolder]
set JAVA_HOME=J:\j2sdk\jdk1.5.0_04
set CLASSPATH="the directory with the classes"
%JAVA_HOME%/bin/javaw -cp "%CLASSPATH%" [name of the class with the main method]
```

Comment: Tom gave a UNC style path and used a Microsoft Windows environment variable expansion, so my example is for windows. I have edited the answer to indicate this.

Comment: Yes, that's a good argument, but remember that Tom won´t be the only person reading your answer, so try to be accurate every time you can :).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're running windows you can map the remote server and folder to some drive and use it:

net use x: \SomeServer\SomeShare

set JAVA_HOME=x:\JDK_PATH_GOES_HERE

set CLASSPATH=....

%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java ....

Hope this helps